# How fast should the camera board be?

Tags: camera

What is a reasonable speed to expect from the raspberry pi camera board?  It seems to take about 15-20 seconds per photo in some cases - is this just how it works or are there some hidden settings that need to be changed?

I am using RaspiStill - I'm just entering

```
raspistill -o test.jpg
```

Comment: What are you using to take picture with the camera board?  Using the default camera software I can take a picture almost instantaneously.

Comment: Are you running resource intensive software when running that command?  Are you sure you connected the camera properly (the connectors are not loose or something)?

Comment: You wont get more than 5~6 FPS because of the internal buffering and inefficient encoding. The foundation is working on this, especially the V2L driver. This will finally enable use to get 60FPS Full HD JPG! But that is on the way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running that command on it's own will use the default delay (between 10 and 30 seconds, can't remember off the top of my head).

If you want to specify a delay you need to pass the `-t` parameter to raspistill.

e.g. `raspistill -o test.jpg -t 5000` will take a photo after a 5 second time delay.

Comment: Be aware that the delay is there for the camera to determine the correct exposure settings.  If you set it too short you may not get correctly exposed photos.

Comment: A very good point, probably something I should have mentioned as I have been having problems with exposure lately and this was one of the problems.